# Loop and break correctly

Tags: python, loops, break

I would like to correctly loop and break this code. This works fine looping through but will not terminate properly

```
from random import randint
import pyttsx

tries = 10
while tries:
    try:
        def random_with_N_digits(n):
            range_start = 10**(n-1)
            range_end = (10**n)-1
            return randint(range_start, range_end)

        randoms = random_with_N_digits(3)
        def speech_recog():
            engine = pyttsx.init()
            engine.say(randoms)
            engine.runAndWait()

        speech_recog()

        def guesses():
            my_guess = raw_input("Enter ")
            count_correct = 0
            count_wrong = 0
            if my_guess == randoms:
                print("correct")
                count_correct +=1
            else:
                count_wrong +=1
    except ValueError:
        break
    guesses() 
print("You got right", count_correct)
print("You got wrong", count_wrong)
#print("Your correct ratio is", count_correct / count_wrong)
print("While loop has exited")
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updating the `tries` variable, so apart from the `ValueError` why do you think the loop should end?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Will see how it works

Answer (score 0):

### First things first - your problem

Your `try... except` is outside of the `while` loop and that is probably why the `break` code doesn't break the while loop.

### Second - coding style (avoid similar problems down the road)

Your functions' definitions should go outside the loop. The loop's purpose is  to **call** these functions.

If you know the number of iterations ahead of execution and it does not depend on the program state, why not use a for loop?
This will help you avoid infinite loops.

Please try to avoid using `try...except` mechanism as a flow control structure. Do so **only** if you must and only if you need a special case of error handling.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think a for loop will be a better option if I need only say 10 times loop.

Comment: Yes. As @rushi answered below, you need to modify `tries` variable if you want the `while` loop to advance. The use of `for _ in range(10)` (`range()` for Python 3.x or `xrange()` for Python 2.7) limits the loop to 10 iterations without the need to modify the loop variable. Please note that even in `for` loops you still need to handle exceptions correctly.